# What does "linear processing" mean in MapReduce? How is it different from Spark's method of data processing?

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce

I know that MapReduce uses linear processing, but what does the "linear" part actually mean?

Also, how is it different from the way Spark processes data?

Comment: Linear (a straight line), vs parallel (multiple lines).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how a "straight line" applies to the functioning of MapReduce?

Comment: Linear processing refers to a process that proceeds in a straight line from start to finish. Simple as that.

Comment: Based on every resource that I've read about MapReduce, it uses parallel processing. Could you please reconcile this with "linear processing"? https://www.ibm.com/analytics/hadoop/mapreduce

Comment: *The first is the map job, which takes a set of data and converts it into another set of data, where individual elements are broken down into tuples (key/value pairs).

The reduce job takes the output from a map as input and combines those data tuples into a smaller set of tuples. As the sequence of the name MapReduce implies, the reduce job is always performed after the map job.*

Comment: Are you trying to say that "linear" really means "sequential", and that MapReduce must run Map and Reduce in sequence?

Comment: I'm not saying that, the article you linked to is saying that.

Answer (score 0):

MapReduce is linear it means work step by step and he don't know what happens in the next step so do the first step, then transfer it to Hardisk,work without plan,
However spark is till the action in trigger non of transformation work,
spark is a lazy work plan that means analyzing all code and understanding it creating a plan then waiting when the user request action, spark starts to execute line by line